# Check object navigational property for existence

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is there a way in C# to check if a navigational property exists without getting an `The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations...` exception ?

For example, if entity framework is used to load an `Animal` object which has  a `Habitat` navigational property and you do `animal.Habitat != null` this will throw a `The ObjectContext instance...` exception.

Any ideas?

Comment: That is how you would check it and it should not throw an exception. But since it is throwing in your case, we need to see your code to help you out. Please post enough code so we can see what the problem may be

Comment: You're attempting to access the navigation property, which is lazy loaded, after the owning context has been disposed.  We need to see more code.

Comment: Yes, the context has been disposed as we use EF contexts in a disconnected state. So in one service method the `animal` has been loaded then passed to a method where we're doing "stuff" with the `animal`. And that navigational property wasn't eager loaded in the service method. The exception makes sense now - I'm asking EF to complete something it's unable to do because there isn't a context.

Answer (score 0):

You must include this object into the query result so that you can still access after data context is disposed of.

```
ctx.animal.Include(m => m.Habitat).FirstOrDefault();
```